# Is my GT 430 bottleneck my perfomance? or is there any other factor?

Tags: graphics-card, performance, upgrade

I have a **performance issue** lately with my computer and here is my computer spec,

**Intel i5-2500k

Nvidia GT 430

8GB of RAM (DDR3)

With motherboard, ASUS P8H61-M LE

OS : Windows 7 64 bit**

What i want is an **upgrade** for my **graphics cards**
**Will i see a huge performance boost?**

And if i must change the graphics cards **do i need to upgrade the motherboard** as well?
 for PCI-E compatibility.

**I use my computer for many things**...

Thanks for the help!
And sorry for my noobness and english...

Edited : to make the post shorter

Comment: Please restrict yourself to asking a single question. Also, hardware recommendations are considered off-topic here, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That graphics card was already low end when it came out. Just buy a new one. You can go high-end without problems, your CPU is plenty fast.

The brands are NVIDIA and AMD (formerly ATI) by the way.